# Inserting new XML attribute using .modify() - how to make it last attribute?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I am trying to update the data in an XML column, and add a new attribute if it doesn't already exist.

Here is the most relevant portion of my script:

```
UPDATE sp
set [PolicyXML].modify
    ('insert attribute source {sql:variable("@source")}
    into (/policies/policy[@type=sql:variable("@policyType")]/groups/group[@id=sql:variable("@groupId") and @accessPermissions=sql:variable("@accessPermissions") and @domainId=sql:variable("@domainId") and not (@source)])[1]
    ')
FROM #spTemp as sp
```

After the change, the data in question becomes:

```
<policies xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <policy type="default">
    <groups>
      <group id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" source="ZZ_MYNEWVALUE_ZZ" accessPermissions="31" domainId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
    </groups>
  </policy>
</policies>
```

But what I need is:

```
<policies xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <policy type="default">
    <groups>
      <group id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" accessPermissions="31" domainId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" source="ZZ_MYNEWVALUE_ZZ" />
    </groups>
  </policy>
</policies>
```

Every article on the internet that I can seem to find talks about using "as last into" instead of just "into" but that seems to be for making a node the last node, not for making an attribute the last attribute. It has no effect here.

Anyone know how to make this new attribute come last?

Comment: According to [this specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-attr) the order of attributes *is not significant* (while the order of element is). Even if you manage to get the attribute into a given place, the next time you open it, it might appear somewhere else...

Comment: That seems right. I wasn't sure if it would still be true if we are using a schema definition, but it seems to be indifferent to order in that case as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to the decision with `insert`, and then `delete`.

```
declare @spTemp table(PolicyXML xml);

declare @policyType nvarchar(max)='default',
        @source nvarchar(max)='ZZ_MYNEWVALUE_ZZ',
        @groupId nvarchar(max)='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
        @accessPermissions nvarchar(max)='31',
        @domainId nvarchar(max)='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
        @px xml='
<policies xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <policy type="default">
    <groups>
      <group id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
             accessPermissions="31"
             domainId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
    </groups>
  </policy>
</policies>';

insert into @spTemp(PolicyXML) values(@px);

UPDATE @spTemp SET PolicyXML.modify('
insert (
for $g in /policies/policy[@type=sql:variable("@policyType")]/groups
          /group[@id=sql:variable("@groupId") and not (@source) and
                 @accessPermissions=sql:variable("@accessPermissions") and
                 @domainId=sql:variable("@domainId")]
  return
    <group>
      {$g/@*}
      {attribute source {sql:variable("@source")}}
    </group>
) after (/policies/policy[@type=sql:variable("@policyType")]/groups
         /group[@id=sql:variable("@groupId") and not (@source) and
                @accessPermissions=sql:variable("@accessPermissions") and
                @domainId=sql:variable("@domainId")])[1]')
OUTPUT INSERTED.PolicyXML as ins_px,DELETED.PolicyXML del_px
WHERE PolicyXML.exist('
/policies/policy[@type=sql:variable("@policyType")]/groups
/group[@id=sql:variable("@groupId") and not (@source) and
       @accessPermissions=sql:variable("@accessPermissions") and
       @domainId=sql:variable("@domainId")]')=1;

UPDATE @spTemp SET PolicyXML.modify('
delete /policies/policy[@type=sql:variable("@policyType")]/groups
       /group[@id=sql:variable("@groupId") and not (@source) and
              @accessPermissions=sql:variable("@accessPermissions") and
              @domainId=sql:variable("@domainId")]')
OUTPUT INSERTED.PolicyXML as ins_px,DELETED.PolicyXML del_px
WHERE PolicyXML.exist('
/policies/policy[@type=sql:variable("@policyType")]/groups
/group[@id=sql:variable("@groupId") and not (@source) and
       @accessPermissions=sql:variable("@accessPermissions") and
       @domainId=sql:variable("@domainId")]')=1;
```

Comment: That will do the trick. Unfortunately for my use, this will slow things down quite a bit.
I will probably just let the attribute come 2nd, and then go through the steps to test that nothing that consumes it has any issues with the order.
Good answer, though.